# Typo3 - t3jquery integration is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, typo3

so first i have to say that i'm realy new to Typo3, so i dont rly know much about the cms.
Actually i have a Problem with my Page.
I want to integrade a Image Slider in my Page with the Nivo Slider Plugin.

The Problem is, that the Slider is not shown.

The page gives the error

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).nivoSlider is not a function
```

so i think, there is some problem with the jQuery.
For that i installed t3jquery but its still not working.

i nearly tried every configuration for t3jquery and also analysed the other extensions on my Page with the plugin, but nothing works.

Some of you have advice what i can do?

The page is hxxp://www.eventbringer.de/skireisen/opening-slider/ (so you can see the error in the JS Console)

Comment: which extension is this exactly (link it from repo) unfortunately your link doesn't work anymore, so I can't check what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPO3 has a very versatile way of getting content of code to the front-end.
One way is to use typoscript.

read : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/

You can see typoscript as a huge configuration 'array' that can declare all sorts of settings.

One of the settings is about how the 'page' itself needs to have.

If you need, for example, some javascript in your page, you could use 
page.includeJs

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#setup-page-includejs-array

if you need yous JS at the footer, and its an external lib, you could use

```
includeJSLibs.twitter = http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js
includeJSLibs.twitter.external = 1
```

Comment: Is this also working with t3query? There i s Alfready a Plugin running which uses jquery. The problem Is , that Both of them Need Different versions. Thats why i Need t3 query